# PHP Mustache Array Iteration

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, mustache

Could you please tell me ways to iterate PHP Mustache array values inside jquery using for loop?

I have tried using below. But it returned all the values inside the array when I swipe. It should return one by one when swipe each time.

```
$('#b').live('swiperight', function() {
var template = 
"{{#users.length}}\
    <ul>\
        {{#users}}\
            <li>{{.}}</li>\
        {{/users}}\
    </ul>\
{{/users.length}}\
{{^users.length}}\
    <p>No Users</p>\
{{/users.length}}";
    var users=new Array();
var users={ users: ['Tom', 'Jerry'] };

var data = 
$("#results").append(Mustache.render(template,users ));
    $('#results').toggle();
    $('#b').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9V4u3/3/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some more information. How did you make that array (and why?!), what is an "PHP Mustache array" anyway, how can it be a "php array" if it is in jquery? what did you try? (you've just posted a string, not anything resembling trying to itterate?), what button? what is your goal anyway? what do you expect and what did you get? As you can see: the question you post only raises questions, please provide some more info and put some effort in making a good question.

Comment: Hi Nanne, i have edited the question now with example

Comment: Are you saying that you are expecting the first user to appear on the first swipe, and the second user on the second swipe?